# Get first element of std::tuple satisfying trait

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

I'm using C++17. I'd like to get an element of a tuple that satisfies some type trait. It would be amazing if the trait could be supplied generically, but I'd be satisfied with a specific function for a certain trait. Usage might look something like this:

```
auto my_tuple = std::make_tuple { 0.f, 1 };

auto basic = get_if_integral (my_tuple);
auto fancy = get_if<std::is_floating_point> (my_tuple);

std::cout << basic; // '1'
std::cout << fancy; // '0.f'
```

Ideally this would fail to compile if more than one element satisfies the trait, like `std::get (std::tuple)`.

Comment: For me it is unclear what your question is. What is wrong with `std::get_if<float>(my_tuple)`?

Comment: That would be just `std::get<float> (my_tuple)`, I think. The context I'm using it is a little more complex, this is just an example. 

I have a tuple of tuples, and I want to return a reference to the first inner tuple that satisfies some trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a surprisingly simple way without using recursion:

```
template <template <typename...> typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr int index_of_integral(const T<Ts...>&)
{
    const bool a[] = { std::is_integral_v<Ts>... };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof...(Ts); ++i) if (a[i]) return i;
    return -1;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) get_if_integral(T&& t)
{
    return std::get<index_of_integral(t)>(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto t = std::make_tuple(3.14, 42, "xyzzy");
    static_assert(get_if_integral(t) == 42);
}
```

It could easily be extended to be parametrized on the trait.

The only things that make it C++17 are the `is_integral_v` variable template and the single-argument `static_assert`. Everything else is C++14.

Note that in C++20 the `for` loop could be replaced with `std::find` and `std::distance`.

Ideally it should throw an exception instead of returning -1, but compilers don't seem to like that.

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224118/1639256).

Comment: That's very nifty indeed!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you want... I propose an helper struct `gf_h` ("get first helper") as follows

```
template <std::size_t, bool ...>
struct gf_h
 { };

template <std::size_t I, bool ... Bs>
struct gf_h<I, false, Bs...> : public gf_h<I+1u, Bs...>
 { };

template <std::size_t I, bool ... Bs>
struct gf_h<I, true, Bs...> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>
 { };
```

and a couple of functions that use it:

```
template <typename ... Us,
   std::size_t I = gf_h<0, std::is_integral<Us>::value...>::value>
auto get_first_integral (std::tuple<Us...> const & t)
 { return std::get<I>(t); }

template <typename ... Us,
   std::size_t I = gf_h<0, std::is_floating_point<Us>::value...>::value>
auto get_first_floating (std::tuple<Us...> const & t)
 { return std::get<I>(t); }
```

Observe that are SFINAE enabled/disabled functions, so are enabled only if there is an integral (or float) value in the tuple

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t, bool ...>
struct gf_h
 { };

template <std::size_t I, bool ... Bs>
struct gf_h<I, false, Bs...> : public gf_h<I+1u, Bs...>
 { };

template <std::size_t I, bool ... Bs>
struct gf_h<I, true, Bs...> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>
 { };

template <typename ... Us,
   std::size_t I = gf_h<0, std::is_integral<Us>::value...>::value>
auto get_first_integral (std::tuple<Us...> const & t)
 { return std::get<I>(t); }

template <typename ... Us,
   std::size_t I = gf_h<0, std::is_floating_point<Us>::value...>::value>
auto get_first_floating (std::tuple<Us...> const & t)
 { return std::get<I>(t); }

int main()
 {
   auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(3.f, 2., 1, 0);

   std::cout << get_first_integral(tup1) << std::endl; // 1
   std::cout << get_first_floating(tup1) << std::endl; // 3

   auto tup2 = std::make_tuple("abc", 4, 5);

   std::cout << get_first_integral(tup2) << std::endl; // 4
   // std::cout << get_first_floating(tup2) << std::endl; // error

   auto tup3 = std::make_tuple("xyz", 6., 7.f);

   // std::cout << get_first_integral(tup3) << std::endl; // error
   std::cout << get_first_floating(tup3) << std::endl; // 6
 }
```

Comment: Ah very nice! This is easier to extend than the solution I found. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a way to accomplish this in a way that is not generic over the trait, but that's good enough for my current purpose. Using `if constexpr` this really doesn't look too bad. I'm sure this isn't hugely idiomatic, but it works for me:

```
template <std::size_t Idx, typename... Us>
auto& get_if_integral_impl (std::tuple<Us...>& t)
{
    static_assert (Idx < std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<Us...>>,
                   "No integral elements in this tuple.");

    if constexpr (std::is_integral<std::tuple_element_t<Idx, std::tuple<Us...>>>::value)
        return std::get<Idx> (t);
    else
        return get_if_integral_impl<Idx + 1> (t);
}

template<typename... Us>
auto& get_if_integral (std::tuple<Us...>& t)
{
    return get_if_integral_impl<0> (t);
}

auto tup = std::make_tuple (3.f, 2., 1, 0);
std::cout << get_if_integral (tup); // '1'
```

My use case is a little more complex, involving returning the first nested tuple which itself contains another type, but this should convey the basic idea.